# Difference between two numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-difference

I have two arrays, for example:

```
array1=numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
array2=numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
```

How can I find the difference between these two arrays in Python, to give:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

As an array as well?

Sorry if this is an amateur question - but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 70):

This is pretty simple with `numpy`, just subtract the arrays:

```
diffs = array1 - array2
```

I get:

```
diffs == array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3])
```

Answer (score 22):

You can also use `numpy.subtract`

It has the advantage over the difference operator, `-`, that you do not have to transform the *sequences* (list or tuples) into a *numpy arrays* — you save the two commands:

```
array1 = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
array2 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

**Example:** (Python 3.5)

```
import numpy as np
result = np.subtract([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1, 2, 3])
print ('the difference =', result)
```

which gives you

```
the difference = [ 0.1  0.2  0.3]
```

Remember, however, that if you try to subtract sequences (lists or tuples) with the `-` operator you will get an error. In this case, you need the above commands to transform the sequences in *numpy arrays*

**Wrong Code:**

```
print([1.1, 2.2, 3.3] - [1, 2, 3])
```